# Azure DevOps: Unable to create branch in specific path

Tags: azure-devops

I'm suddenly unable to create a branch under our `releases` folder. I'm a project administrator and my permissions seem to allow me to. My colleague is able to and he is also a project administrator.

Error:
[image]

It should also be noted that I get the same error trying to do it via CLI.

Checking repository permissions, I see these security permissions on `All Branches` (these are mine):
[image]

Checking the security permissions on the `releases` folder itself, I see this (also my permissions):
[image]

Looking at my colleagues permissions on the `releases` folder itself, I see this:
[image]

Any ideas on why I'm suddenly not able to do this branching? I can branch to any other location on the repo (root, other folders, etc).

Update 1/4/2023:
Per promico's suggestion, I ran the `tf git permission` and found no denials.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out after my colleague reminded me that months ago I had restricted who could create branches under `releases` as we had one dev who wouldn't stop making patch branches under it.  `Contributors` were not allowed to create branches under `releases`, but `Release Administrators` could. It would seem that some teams/permissions tidying changed something somewhere in my permissions that I lost the permission even though I'm in both.  For context, my colleague that could still create `releases` branches is also in both so he must have an elevated permission somewhere that I don't.

Regardless, I found the permission by running this command from a dev powershell:

```
tf git permission /collection:https://[REDACTED] /teamproject:[REDACTED] /repository:[REDACTED] /branch:releases
```

That returned a list of permissions specific to the `releases` branch and included:

[image]

I followed up with a command to re-enable the `CreateBranch` permission for `Contributors`:

```
tf git permission /collection:https://[REDACTED] /teamproject:[REDACTED] /repository:[REDACTED] /branch:releases /allow:CreateBranch /group:[REDACTED]\Contributors
```

Thank you, @promicro, for helping this along! Appreciate the effort!

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help and that this is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this visualstudio topic:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-create-new-branch-git-error-vs403660/1049986

I don’t know how accurate this info is, but with `tf.exe` git stuff like this can be done and undone, it might help since your problems are locally.

https://msftplayground.com/2019/03/meet-the-specified-naming-conventions-in-azure-devops-git/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/git-permission-command?view=azure-devops

### UPDATE

Can it be that your account has more group memberships then your colleague? I made myself part of another group with a deny on creating a branch and got this message:
[image]

A deny outweighs your administrator allow.

Of course your problem is not `CreateBranch`, it clearly states `ref naming convention`, but combining this with my earlier answer:

- Are you part of other groups then your colleague?
- Did you verify the permission on this repo with `tf git permission`?

I still think it is in the corner of `tf git permission`...
Jesse Houwing wrote a blog post about crunching these permissions, which also could be handy:
https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/

### 2nd Update

For the repo, but also for all repos a detailed permission report can be downloaded (via a request):
[image]
[image]

Maybe this json report contains the info to solve this?

Comment: I did see that. Didn't help.  Also, see my update that this is not a local issue.

Comment: Rethink is finally done ;-)

Comment: I ran `tf git permission` and updated my question with the results. Doesn't seem to be the issue. As far as groups, my colleague and I are in the same groups though he's in a few groups in other projects within the organization.

Comment: @MattM I see no denies on your screenshot, very strange! But what if you explicitly add an Allow for your user (group). See this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Comment: never mind I see that `CreateBranch` is already there... man what a vague problem is this. For the record is this in all repos or a specific one...The error in your screenshot says 'scope repository'

Comment: This is across repos and only effects the `releases` folder. For instance, I can create `test/1`.

Comment: @MattM Ok across all repos? Did the download like stated in my 2nd update help?

Comment: That button is not available to me. I don't own the org, I'm just an admin on the project so maybe that's why?

Comment: @MattM I checked it on a project on which I’m not an org admin just project admin, and I can confirm that the button is NOT available. Maybe you can ask someone with enough rights…