# Why can't I select a source branch in DevOps when creating a branch from the task board?

Tags: git, devops

In DevOps I'm able to navigate to Repos -> Branches -> Create new branch. This gives me a dialog box which gives me an option to select the branch to base my new branch off of.

However if I attempt to create a branch by navigating to Boards -> Sprints -> Story/Task Item and click "Create a branch" I can't see the dropdown which allows me to select a source branch. The only dropdown shown is the one selecting the repository.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

According to the following topic: [Azure DevOps: Unable to create branch in specific path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817663/azure-devops-unable-to-create-branch-in-specific-path)
Thats the most valuable answer

Have you checked this visualstudio topic: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-create-new-branch-git-error-vs403660/1049986

I don’t know how accurate this info is, but with tf.exe git stuff like this can be done and undone, it might help since your problems are locally.

https://msftplayground.com/2019/03/meet-the-specified-naming-conventions-in-azure-devops-git/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/git-permission-command?view=azure-devops

**UPDATE**

Can it be that your account has more group memberships then your colleague? I made myself part of another group with a deny on creating a branch and got this message:
[image]

A deny outweighs your administrator allow.

Of course your problem is not CreateBranch, it clearly states ref naming convention, but combining this with my earlier answer:

Are you part of other groups then your colleague?
Did you verify the permission on this repo with tf git permission?
I still think it is in the corner of tf git permission... Jesse Houwing wrote a blog post about crunching these permissions, which also could be handy: https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/

**2nd Update**

For the repo, but also for all repos a detailed permission report can be downloaded (via a request):

[image]

Maybe this json report contains the info to solve this?